# How to get pid given the process name

Tags: unix, ksh, pid

Hi I have searched various forums and here as well, I could find some answers for Linux and Mac but not able to find solution for Unix and specially Korn Shell.

How to get process name (command name) from process id (pid)

Below reference I found from Stack Overflow
[This one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4189717/get-process-name-by-pid) 
[And this one also](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15545341/process-name-from-its-pid-in-linux)

I tried the below command

```
ps -eaf | awk '{ print substr($0, index($0, $9)) }'
```

The above command is failing at a point where TIME is given rather than Month and Date (because in this case there will be only 8 columns in string)

Any suggestion would help.

Comment: No I want pid from process name, it was wrongly type in title

Comment: This issue is very specific to your version of unix and has little to do with the shell. Please include the output of `uname -a`.

Comment: For Mac users who happen to find this, see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11546765/how-to-get-the-pid-of-a-process-by-giving-the-process-name-in-mac-os-x.

Answer (score 120):

I think it is easier to use [`pgrep`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/pgrep)

```
$ pgrep bluetoothd
441
```

Otherwise, you can use `awk`:

```
ps -ef | awk '$8=="name_of_process" {print $2}'
```

For example, if `ps -ef`has a line like:

```
root       441     1  0 10:02 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/bluetoothd
```

Then `ps -ef | awk '$8=="/usr/sbin/bluetoothd" {print $2}'` returns `441`.

---

> In ksh pgrep is not found. and the other solution is failing in case
>   below is output from ps command jaggsmca325 7550 4752 0 Sep 11 pts/44
>   0:00 sqlplus dummy_user/dummy_password@dummy_schema

Let's check the last column (`$NF`), no matter its number:

```
$ ps -ef | awk '$NF=="/usr/sbin/bluetoothd" {print $2}'
441
```

If you want to match not exact strings, you can use `~` instead:

```
$ ps -ef | awk '$NF~"bluetooth" {print $2}'
441
1906
```

Comment: In ksh pgrep is not found. and the other solution is failing in case below is output from ps command    `jaggsmca325 7550  4752  0  Sep 11  pts/44    0:00 sqlplus dummy_user/dummy_password@dummy_schema`

Comment: I tried your solution and it's pretty working but failing at a point where the process name is having whitespaces like below ps -eaf | awk '$NF=="sshd: jaggsmca325@pts/53" {print $2}' any pointer to that problem? And yea I want to get match exact process name.

Comment: @gahlot.jaggs As I used `$NF`, you can also use `$(NF-1)`, etc. So you could use `$(NF-1)=="sshd:" && $NF=="jaggsmca325@pts/53"`

Comment: Thanks for your all efforts, but I can not know at runtime how many tokens I would be having that time so I can not use $(NF-1) as otherwise it will be fixed to N-1 only and will fail for other cases. Is there any way I could find the process id by using process name, rather than using ps -eaf

Comment: @gahlot.jaggs You can also `grep "process$"`, as `$` means end of line. Then give the string to awk to print the 2nd record.

Comment: `pgrep` works on Ubuntu 14.04. A point to note if you are feeding the output into a script is that if multiple processes share the name, it will print a list of pids, one per line.

Comment: This isn't a good solution, and it requires an exact match of what's almost always a very long command that's impractical to enter. A partial matching solution would be far more useful.

Comment: @Cerin yep, agreed. That's why I offer some alternatives.

Answer (score 13):

You can use **[`pidof`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/pidof)** to get all IDs of running processes with the name `p_name`:

**[`pidof`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/pidof)** `p_name | tr ' ' '\n'` (for a vertical listing)

**[`pkill`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/pkill)** `p_name` - kill all processes whith the name `p_name`

Make sure that you have the permission to kill them all :)

Comment: pidof works for process names longer than 15 characters

Answer (score 1):

If your `ps | awk` solution is failing because the output of `ps` is not what you want, then make it so:

```
ps -eaf -o pid,cmd | awk '/regex-to-match-command-name/{ print $1 }'
```

Comment: It says ps: illegal option -- o

Comment: `ps` varies depending on your platform (but I would think `-o` is standard).  Check your documentation to see how to manipulate the output fields.  (`man ps`)

Comment: `ps` also supports `o` (without the `-`) and `--format`, depending on your platform.

Answer (score 1):

```
ps -C <the-name> -o etime=
```

My ps is from procps-ng .

Comment: I also use `ps -C <process-name> -o user= | head -1` to get process owner (user)