# How send SIGUSR1 signal with a keyboard shortcut?

Tags: node.js, console, signals, kill

I want to send SIGUSR1 signal to my node.js application for debugging via terminal. I know command `kill -SIGUSR1 <pid>`

How can I setup keyboard shortcut for this? If it matters, I use MacOs

Answer (score 7):

Quite old, but for anyone who is looking for answer: SIGUSR (BSD SIGINFO) - ^T (Control and T simultaneously)

Comment: It will send SIGINFO, but question was about SIGUSR1. The difference here https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Miscellaneous-Signals.html#Miscellaneous-Signals

Comment: @galkin for this particular question, this is the working solution

Answer (score 0):

To get the pid of your node.js application:

[How to get the PID of a process by giving the process name in Mac OS X ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11546765/how-to-get-the-pid-of-a-process-by-giving-the-process-name-in-mac-os-x)

To create a global shortcut for your command:

https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/24063/create-global-shortcut-to-run-command-line-applications