# Nodejs - Get environment variables of running process

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, vscode-extensions

I am writing an extension for vscode, and I need to get the environment variables of a process that is already running. But I wasn't able to find a way to do it.

I know how to do it in python using psutil:

```py
for proc in psutil.process_iter(attrs=['name', 'exe']):
    if proc.info['name'].lower() == 'SomeProcess.exe'.lower():
        return proc.environ()
```

Is there something similar for javascript/nodejs?

Comment: process.env is the move.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no builtin way to do that in javascript/nodejs. If you really need to do it, then the best way is to run a command in the terminal and then parse the output to construct the object that you need.

Answer (score 7):

You can use child_process module to spawn a terminal and execute the following commands wrt platform and get the variables, parse & use or write a native node module to access the proper APIs of each platform and get the output.

Windows (Using powershell, 2019 is the PID )

```
(Get-Process -id 2019).StartInfo.EnvironmentVariables
```

Linux

```
tr '\0' '\n' < /proc/2019/environ
```

Mac

```
ps eww -o command 2019  | tr ' ' '\n'
```

Thanks to https://serverfault.com/a/66366 & https://stackoverflow.com/a/28193753/12167785 & https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/254253 &
https://stackoverflow.com/a/11547409/12167785 &
https://stackoverflow.com/a/18765553/12167785

Comment: Does it also work with the Process name instead of the PID?

Comment: (Get-Process -id processnmae).StartInfo.EnvironmentVariables [for windows]

Comment: @psclkhoury I advise you to rely on PID, as there can be more than 1 process with the same name

Comment: Yes sure, but I don't know the process ID. I only know the process name.

Comment: oh. ps -ef | awk '$8=="name_of_process" {print $2}' (linux , get pid from name & then use the answer)

Comment: ps -A | grep -m1 process_name | awk '{print $1}' [Mac]

Comment: @psclkhoury for windows it's just `Get-Process processname` which you can see in other answers.

Answer (score 3):

Combining with @SudhakarRS's answer:

```
var child = require('child_process').execFile('powershell', [ 
    '(Get-Process SomeProcess).StartInfo.EnvironmentVariables' 
], function(err, stdout, stderr) { 
    console.log(stdout);
});
```

If you want to debug it, make sure you peek at `err` and `stderr`.

Replacing `SomeProcess` with `notepad` works for me, but using `notepad.exe` does not.

On powershell you can get the processes with a particular name using `Get-Process [process name]`.

So, for example, if I have 4 instances of notepad running and do `Get-Process notepad`, I see this:

[image: Processes]

You can get the process IDs with `(Get-Process notepad).Id` which returns:

[image]

You could use the same code to choose the ID:

```
var child = require('child_process').execFile(
    'powershell',
    ['(Get-Process notepad).Id'],
    function(err, stdout, stderr) { 
        var ids = stdout.split("\r\n");
        ids.pop(); //remove the blank string at the end
        console.log(ids);
    }
);
```

^ which returns:

[image: Return]

If you just want to grab the first process with a name, it's:

`(Get-Process notepad)[0].StartInfo.EnvironmentVariables`

^ obviously replace `notepad` with your process name.

Answer (score 3):

Easyish way(from [here](https://ma.ttias.be/show-the-environment-variables-of-a-running-process-in-linux/), you can use something like [shelljs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/shelljs) then run:

```
ps faux | grep 'PROCESS_NAME'
```

Then extract the process id(I'm just working on a regex) and then do:

```
cat /proc/THE_PROCESS/environ | tr '\0' '\n'
```

You'll get the the env vars back as a string something like:

```
THEVAR=1
ANOTHERVAR=2
```

I reckon you just split the string by '\n' but I'm checking!

I'll update this once I figure the regex. **Are you on linux/mac or windows?

UPDATE: Check https://github.com/shelljs/shx for cross platform

Comment: I am on Windows, but since this is an extension I would prefer if it works on all platforms with the same solution.

Comment: Hmm ShellJS is supposed to be portable, I can't test it right now but will do asap. Feel free to accept any other relevant answers that solve your particular case, I'd suggest editing the title and description so it includes windows.

Comment: Saying that you could combine these answers and just figure out which platform you're running on to run the right command!

Comment: You want to split with `\r\n` (on windows at least )

Comment: I'll might be able to test it beforehand, I'll do my best!

Answer (score -1):

yep:

`process.env` will give you what you need :)

you can read some more [here](https://codeburst.io/process-env-what-it-is-and-why-when-how-to-use-it-effectively-505d0b2831e7).

*EDIT*: it will give you environment variables only for the process you're **in**... did I misunderstood and you want varibales of another process?